# How to create a custom implementation for Hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate

While investigating one issue with Hibernate, I want to make an experiment and change the default implementation of hibernate session (SessionImpl.java). Actually, I only want to comment out a couple of lines.  One option to do that is to change source code and build custom version of Hibernate, but I would like to try to provide an alternative implementation of the session instead.

I looked at the [hiberante documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/sessionfactory/CustomSessionFactory.html) and it seems possible and it actually described how to do a similar thing. However, I don't want to create a new implementation of the session from the scratch. As the SessionImpl class is final, I tried to copy it but it has too many links to internal stuff, which makes it not feasible to copy paste. The only way I haven't tried yet is to create my classes under `org.hibernate.internal` package name.

I wonder if anyone tried to do a similar thing and had some success with it.

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @Sathish no I abandon the attempt. The issue I tried to solve was a bug in a new version of Hibernate so I had to downgrade Hibernate.